# Can't access appstoreconnect Resolution Center

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

This is crazy.

I recently added three subscription tiers to my iOS app.  Already had one approved and live.  Apple rejected the in app purchase submissions because I left off a link to my terms of use in the app description (used to be there, but somehow I left it off recently.)  I fixed it.

The nutty thing is I can't access the resolution center to reply to their message!  I don't want to resubmit the in app purchases figuring that replying to their message would be much, much faster.  (Took 14 days to receive the rejection.)

Since the apple rejection was not associated with a build, there are no links anywhere in app store connect.  I did find a link to the resolution center for my app but nothing under that link is recent.

Any advice?

- Jon

Comment: If you still have the email that they sent with the rejection notice you can access from there.

Comment: They didn't send me an email :-(  I noticed this morning in app store connect that it was rejected.  On the In app purchases page, it gave me a link to notes from the app review - but not to the resolution center.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Since the redesign - on the My Apps page, clicking on the app's Error Icon takes you to Resolution Center.

Another way is to click on the App Store Tab, then Version History and then Resolution Center.

Answer (score 0):

A happy ending to report.  Never was able to access the resolution center.

While I was deciding whether to email Apple support (again) or delete and resubmit the in app purchases, they were approved by Apple!

I took no action to cause this.  I'm thinking that one of my previous contacts with Apple caused them to re-review the in app purchases and to notice that I updated the app description as they requested.

Quite a surprise.